# Xamarin iOS/Android - what is the architecture pattern (e.g. mvvm?), type of service and database

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I'm trying to create a simple 3-tier (Gui/webservice) ios/andriod app using Xamarin on VS2015.

This is my basic architecture of dev environment

- VS2105 with Xamarin on MVVMCross pattern
- WebApi/HttpClient as middle layer
- CouchBaseDb for auto sync data between device and remote db in the cloud.

Is there anything missing or any setup is wrong ?

Comment: There is no single correct answer for a question like this.  Questions that solicit opinions and discussion are considered off-topic on SO.

Comment: i certainly aware of this ... but .... considert this as a desperate move ... is it really no quick answer at all ? at least having the right "terms" would be a lot easier for me to google up more infomation.

Comment: While this is no final answer, this blog has a nice approach suggestion. It's for Xamarin.Forms, but could easily be adapted for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-architectural-guidance/